# Change value of variable inside SQL query

Tags: mysql, node.js

I hate to ask such a simple question but I can't find an answer anywhere.

I am trying to push the sql results to `results2`, if I print out the `results2` value inside of the connection query it shows the array but when I try to return or print it outside it shows as undefined.

Code:

```
function getUserData(cookie){
  const sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `cookie` = ?"
  const params = [cookie];

  let results2 = [];
  connection.query(sqlquery, params, function(error, results, fields){
    if(error) throw error;
    if(results && results.length){
      results2.push(results[0]);
    }else{
      return("invalid");
    }
  })
  console.log(results2)
  return(results2);
}
```

I have searched and read through documentations but I can't find where I am messing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to the world of callbacks and async ops.

> I am trying to push the sql results to results2, if I print out the
> results2 value inside of the connection query it shows the array but
> when I try to return or print it outside it shows as undefined.

Here `console.log(results2)` runs first and in the callback, you are assigning values to results2. So, you are unable to see it.

You can use await with the query:

```
//const util = require('util');

function getUserData(cookie){
  const sqlquery = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `cookie` = ?"
  const params = [cookie];

  let results2 = [];
  try {
  // if not able to use await promisfy it using 
  // const query  = util.promisify(conn.query).bind(connection);
  // const result = await query(sqlquery, params);
  const result = await connection.query(sqlquery, params);
  results2.push(result);
 } catch(e) {
   console.log(e);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that JavaScript is synchronous (tries to do as much as it can at once) unless you tell it not to be. It is returning `reults2` before it has actually populated it because it is faster for it to do it that way. So you need to make the function as a whole asynchronous by adding `async` before `function` and adding `await` before `connection.query` AND before wherever you are calling getUserData (as in `await getUserData(var1, var2)`).

An explanation of async functions and await is here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

You may start getting errors about functions not begin asynchronous, as async functions need to nest to work (anything that `await`s needs to be in an async function itself).